# Java - Clone list that holds references to original List

Tags: java, list, copy, clone

I don't know exactly how copying a List in Java works. I have this code:

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(original);
```

Would this make a new List called copy that just holds references to the objects in the original list? (This is what I want). Or would it make new string objects and use up unnecessary memory?

And when I remove items from the copy List, will this only remove a reference and not delete the object from both lists?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Will make new String objects.   If you delete from `copy` it will not delete from `original`.  If you do `List<String> copy = original` then you are just making a reference, and altering in `copy` will alter `original`

Comment: @gtgaxiola This won't make new String objects. It'll just populate the list with the same old ones. Also, you don't alter `copy`, you alter the entity "stored in" `copy`, which happens to be the same entity that is "stored in" `original`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `copy` list will contain references to the same `String` objects.  This is known as a *shallow copy*.  It will not create copies of the elements; it will create copies of the references to the elements.

```
original -->  [ +      +       +  ]
                |      |       |
                v      v       v
               "one"  "two" "three"
                ^      ^       ^
                |      |       |
    copy -->  [ +      +       +  ]
```

When you remove an item from one list, you remove the reference only, from that list only.  The corresponding reference in the other list is still intact.

```
original -->  [ +      +       +  ]
                |      |       |
                v      v       v
               "one"  "two" "three"
                ^      ^
                |      |
    copy -->  [ +      +  ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for the late reply. Really made it clear :)

Answer (score 1):

It creates a brand new ArrayList that is populated with the original String objects. You can verify this by using the `==` operator to compare instances ("memory locations"):

```
original.get(0) == copy.get(0) // true
```

The `.remove` method removes the element only from the list you are calling it on. It doesn't blast it out of existince anywhere it may be used (and you can't actually do that in Java). And because the `copy` list is a brand new list and not "backed" by the `original` list, deleting something from the original won't affect the copy.